# How do I make a client-server Java application to send messages on one port but receive them on another?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, port

I am currently trying to make an application that will send messages to a server using one port, but will receive messages on another port.  However, based on tutorials I have followed, it looks like the act of connecting to the server is where ports come into play and my client is receiving and sending messages on the same port.  How do I make it so it sends on one port but receives on the other?

Here is the code that I think is relevant from the client side (I put some stuff that seems unrelated because I think they are things that would be altered by receiving on one port but sending on another, and ignore the comment about replacing inetaddress, that is just me working on implementing this in a gui):

```
public void startRunning(){
    try{
        connectToServer();
        setupStreams();
        whileChatting();

    }catch(EOFException eofException){
        showMessage("\n Client terminated connection");

    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        closeStuff();
    }

}



//connect to server
private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
    showMessage("Attempting connection... \n");
    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 480);//replace serverIP with ipTextField.getText or set serverIP to equal ipTextField.getText? Same with port number.
    showMessage("Connected to:  " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName() );
}


//set up streams to send and receive messages
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    showMessage("\n Streams are good!  \n");
}


//while talking with server
private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
    ableToType(true);
    do{
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotfoundException){
            showMessage("\n Don't know that object type");
        }

    }while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
}

//send messages to server
private void sendMessage(String message){
    try{
        output.writeObject("CLIENT - " + message);
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\nCLIENT - " + message);
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        messageWindow.append("\n something messed up ");
    }

}


//change/update message window
private void showMessage(final String m){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                messageWindow.append(m);
            }
        }
    );

}
```

EDIT/UPDATE:  To help clarify some things, here is some more information.  The device that sends the first message is connected to a sensor, and it sends information when that sensor detects something to the other device.  The receiving device sends a message back on a different port telling the original sending device how to respond.  Lets name these two devices the "reporter-action taker" and the "decision maker-commander".

Comment: It's like a virtual connection, provides the interface between the application and the real network connection.  Something like that.  Basically, its how an application connects to a network versus how a machine running the application connects.  So yes, I do know what a port is, or the general idea anyway.  That isn't what I'm asking.  I'm asking how do I modify the code to send messages via one port but recieve via a different port.

Comment: if you want to use two ports, while sending you can use one port but for whatever you sent if you want a corresponding response then server has to know your receiving port as well? how are you going to send this information? What is the Idea of having 2 ports?

Comment: The client and server both already know what ports are to be used.

Comment: I actually have written most of the code already.  Its simply part of the design.  My code is what determines what port is used.  People, please stop asking or commenting about the fact that I am trying to use multiple ports, I didn't ask for an opinion, as its not my decision whether to anyway, all I wanted was how to do it, not whether I should!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use TCP/IP sockets you can't use a a socket to send and another to read. That's not what they are for.

If you use a centralized distributed algorithm (server/client communication) you have to set the server to listen on a single socket port with the ServerSocket class: then the server tries to accept clients through that socket.

Example:

```
ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(Port)
While (true) {
    new Clienthandler(listener.accept());
}
```

The server will listen on that port, and when a client tries to connect to that port if it is accepted the server launches its handler. On this handler constructor the Socket object used on the client is received on an argument and can then be used to get the writers and the readers. The reader on this handler class will be the writer on the client class and vice-versa, maybe that's what you were looking for.

Comment: What if hypothetically, its UDP?

Comment: It would be very similar with the client and server also connecting and listening on the same port. You can see a simple implementation here https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify, I need to create two different sockets, one for each port to be used, with one listening and the other sending?

Comment: Yes but both of them will listen or connect on the same port otherwise they wont find eachother. The client will not be able to find the server and the server will forever be waiting listening on that port without accepting any client connection.

Comment: Are you saying then that both the server and client have to listen on the same port or that the server has to listen on the port that the client sends on?

Comment: The second thing is exactly it: the server has to listen on the port that the client sends on.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, I can't simply modify my existing code,  I need to rewrite it from the beginning for it to be able to this.  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: You should just listen on the same port when you write the server. In this case its the port 480 wich is the port you try to connect to in the client when you pass the argument 480 to the Socket constructor.

Comment: So, the server will be listening on port 480, and the client will send on port 480, but the server will respond on some other port, which will be setup to be the port that the client listens on?  Is that what you are basically saying I need to do?

Comment: No. Everything happens on port 480. Its the streamreaders and streamwritters that will be used to communicate. The socket ia just a pathway between server an client. Simply a bridge connecting both.

Comment: You lost me there.  I thought this was to make it so messages were sent on one port but received on the other?  Or are you saying that I need to use two different sockets to do this (use one port to send and the other to recieve)?

Comment: To do that yes you would have to use two different sockets and have the server listening on both and have them both instantiated on the client too however that is extremelly not pratical. Is there a specific reason why you want to do that? because that is not the standard way to plan a distributed system and it may also be a bit confusing if there is not a strong reason to do it.

Comment: Simply the specs I was given, using one port to send and the other port to receive.  I haven't asked why, because I have been asking other questions about the design lol, that was small potatoes compared to my other questions I asked the person who gave me the design.

Comment: Ok maybe there is another reason why. But if you wish to do it like that then you have to instatiate two serverSocket on the server side, use their accept method to acept the client connection (use it on both serversocket) and then pass each socket they return to the client handler's constructor where you will get inputstream for one socket and outputstream from the other. On the client side just create two sockets and connect. The port has to be different on each socket of course

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Seems like a lot of extra work as you said, but the solution at least seems a lot more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Your question about using two ports in this manner is a bit strange. You state that you have a client and a server and that they should communicate on different ports.

Just to clarify picture the server as a hanging rack for jackets with several hooks in a row. Each port the server listened on represents a hook. When it comes to the client server relationship the client or jacket knows where to find its hook, however the hook is blind and have no idea where to find jackets.

Now, the client selects a port or a hook and connects to it. The connection is like a pipeline with two pipes. One for the client to deliver data to the server with and the other to send data from the server back to the client. When the connection is established data can be transferred both ways. This means that we only need one port open on the server to send data both from the client to the server and in the opposite direction.

The reason for only having one open port open on the server for the clients to connect to is that holding an open port for connections is hard to do on a regular client computer. The normal desktop user will be behind several firewalls blocking incoming connections. If that wasn't the case the client would probably be hacked senseless from malicious viruses.

Moving on with the two port solution we could not call this a client server connection per say. It would be more like a peer to peer connection or something like that. But if this is what you want to do, the application connecting first would have to start by telling the other application what ip and port to use for connecting back, it should probably also want to give some kind of token that are to be used to pair the new incoming connection when connecting back.

You should take note that making such an implementation is not a good idea most of the time as it complicates things a whole lot for simple data transfer between a client and server application.

Comment: It is actually quite possible that the design meant the connection to be a p2p as opposed to client-server.  I didn't write up the design documentation, so sometimes its hard to determine the actual intent of certain elements.  If its helpful, here is a bit more info:  one device sends a message notifying another device of an event occurring, including info of what the event actually is.  The other device sends a message back telling the event sender how to respond and what to do next.  Eventually, it tells the event sender to reset and watch for new events.